# Goland run/re-run command from button click

Tags: go, goland

I am using `go run` command to execute my go file manually.

Running `main.go` file in `web` directory: `go run ./cmd/web`

After any changes: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and then `go run ./cmd/web` again

Is there a way to do It from button in Goland? Or maybe automatically when go code changes?

Comment: Take a look at this project https://github.com/canthefason/go-watcher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read [the help article](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/go/running-applications.html) on how to run applications/tests directly from the IDE, without having to type the `go run` command.

As a quick reference:

> In the left gutter of the editor, click the Run application icon the Run Application icon and select Run < method_name > in < file_name >.